# Deleting rows TOTALLY except first

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I'm struggling with Visual Basic in Excel to delete completely all rows in the sheet except the first six rows. 
Here I illustrate my code associated with a command button:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim tot_rows As Integer

tot_rows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NAME").UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("NAME")

For i = tot_rows To 6 Step -1
        .Rows(i).ClearContents
        .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

When I execute the code it does no delete a single row, can you tell me why? 
tot_rows is always equal to 401 (and in the sheet I can see 401 rows so I assume it's correct).
Could be more than 401 rows which I cannot visually see?

Thank you for any help, I appreciate

Comment: Just to be sure, since the code looks fine, are you certain that `tot_rows` is being set correctly. Can you put a breakpoint (F9) on your `With` line, run the code, and check the value of `tot_rows` in your Locals pane (Use view>>Locals) if you don't have that up already in your VBE.

Comment: Or you can just do it in one line of code after you determine the last row... `Sheets("Name").Range("A2:Z" & tot_rows).Delete`

Comment: Where is your `End With`?

Comment: Your narrative states *'except the first six rows'* but your code does delete row 6.

Comment: tot_rows is 401.

Answer (score 0):

.UsedRange can be squirrelly; particularly when your data is not in a contiguous block expanding out from row 1.

```
dim lr as long, lc as long

with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = .cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    lc = .cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column
    .range(.cells(7, 1), .cells(lr, lc)).clear
end with
```

If you are 'deleting' all of the rows then you just need to clear them as a block. No loop; no delete.

For all intents and purposes, there is no reason that this will not do what you are attempting.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    .range(.cells(7, 1), .cells(.rows.count, .columns.count)).clear
end with
```

Comment: Well, you last code gives me the same answer: nothing happens.

Comment: And I'm sure your code is perfect, I sincerely don't know what to do

Comment: Open a new blank workbook and fill sheet1 with some random values then run the code.

Comment: Your code and my code work. The problem is I don't want to clear the contents only, I want not to see lines 6+ anymore.

Comment: `.ClearContents` will only clear the values leaving the formatting. `.Clear` clears everything; all the values, formulas and formatting. If you have anything remaining, it might be because you have styles or conditional formatting which override the worksheet format.

Comment: Actually, I believe you have a structured listobject table. As you are not deleting the entire table, the table style is being retained for the whole structured table object.

Comment: The content is cleared but the cells remain blank. Is it possible to completely delete them?